# Search within yearly quarter

Tags: sql, date

Hello I'm trying to figure out how many different EFTs my company runs each quarter then year to date. Is it possible to do something like this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT Client_no FROM Flat_xTransactions
WHERE SCode = 'EFT Active'
AND Last_Mdt < "April 1st of whatever year the report is ran"
```

Thanks!

Comment: What rdmbs are you working with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Client_no FROM Flat_xTransactions
WHERE SCode = 'EFT Active'
AND DATEPART(MONTH,Last_Mdt)<4 and DATEPART(Year,Last_Mdt)=@Year
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify your DBMS, so this is standard ANSI SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Client_no 
FROM Flat_xTransactions
WHERE SCode = 'EFT Active'
AND (extract(year from Last_Mdt), extract(month from last_mdt)) < (extract(year from current_date), 4);
```

If it you need a different day then the 1st of the month, then you need to include the day as well in the comparison, but for the 1st it's not necessary.

Depending on your DBMS there might be more efficient ways of doing that.